# How to make Wordpress search require a specific number of characters

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I need to make Wordpress searches require at least 12 characters in order to return results, or possibly have the search automatically put quotes around the search so it only brings back results that match exactly. My client has 3 pages that have the word "Minnesota" in them but only wants searches to come back if they match the whole title, not just one word.

I have a very minimal test site set up with only the Relevanssi plugin installed.

```
<?php
// Get the query string
$query = get_search_query();
// if the first & last char is space, rip them
$query = trim($query);
// if there are more than one space, rip to one space
$query = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$query);
// if chars count is less than  12, redirect them to homepage
if (strlen($query)<12){
wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
exit; 
}
?>
```

---

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_make_search_exact', 10);
function my_make_search_exact($query){

if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) :
    $query->set('exact', true);
endif;

}
```

I've tried the first code example above in the search.php file. It creates an error on the page. Same results if I put in the functions.php file

The second one works in the functions.php file, but if you search for "Minnesota" all three pages come up.

Comment: See also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56279/set-minimum-number-of-characters-in-the-search

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a WordPress answer to your question, but couldn't you just use the HTML5 minlength in your searchform input?

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" minlength="12" value="" id="s" placeholder="Search&hellip;"`>